# Como hacer un patch general en JS con express?

Tags: javascript, json, api, express, rest

Mi programa esta corriendo en memoria y almaceno mi json en una lista asi:

```
var list = [
{
  [json schema]
}]
```

y usando este [json schema](https://jsonresume.org/schema/) quiero cambiar cualquier campo del json mediante un patch, por ejmplo

teniendo este json:

```
{
"work": [{
"company": "Company",
"position": "President",
"website": "http://company.com",
"startDate": "2013-01-01",
"endDate": "2014-01-01",
"summary": "Description...",
"highlights": [
  "Started the company"
]}]}
```

y con un patch mandandole esta propiedad en el body del request

```
{
 "position": "Employer"
}
```

quiero cambiar el campo position de presidente a empleador, y esto hacerlo con cualquier campo que tenga el json

Comment: Lo que quieres cambiar es el `.json` es decir, el archivo que contiene la informacion o simplemente el objeto parseado en `js`?

Comment: Quiero cambiar solo el objeto que le mandare en el body pero el resto del json se quedaria igual

Comment: ya revisastes la respuesta que te puse? , saludos

Comment: Si, lo estoy viendo justo ahora, no es especificamente lo que necesitaba pero me diste una muy buena idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Si, mas bien lo que te hice un ejemplo base de como podrias manejar los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basandome en que el `json` ya lo tienes como un objecto:

```js
let json = {
  work: [
{
  company: "Company",
  position: "President",
  website: "http://company.com",
  startDate: "2013-01-01",
  endDate: "2014-01-01",
  summary: "Description...",
  highlights: ["Started the company"],
},
  ],
};

const request = {
"position": "Employer"
};
const requestTwo = {
"company": "Other company"
};
function changeJSON(jsonObject, req) {
  const toChange = Object.keys(req)[0];
  const newValue = Object.values(req)[0];

  const newObj = jsonObject.work.map((item) => {
return { ...item, [toChange]: newValue };
  });
  return newObj;
}

const response = changeJSON(json, request);
console.log('first response: ',response);
const responseTwo = changeJSON(json, requestTwo);
console.log('second response: ',responseTwo);
```